# How to make an alternating responsive grid?

Tags: html, css, pure-css

I have a 2-column grid as follows: some text, followed by an image related to that text. On the other row the order is flipped:

```
| Text 1           | Image for Text 1 |
| Image for Text 2 | Text 2           |
| Text 3           | Image for Text 3 |
```

I created a standard grid to achieve it (jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6yxLpqmr/), extract from source:

```
<div class="pure-g">
  <article class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-2">Text 1</article>
  <article class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-2">Image for Text 1</article>
  <article class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-2">Image for Text 2</article>
  <article class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-2">Text 2</article>
  <article class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-2">Text 3</article>
  <article class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-2">Image for Text 3</article>
  <!-- many more alternating articles like this -->
</div>
```

However, once the grid is collapsed on a narrow screen, it results in:

```
Text 1
Image for Text 1
Image for Text 2
Text 2
Text 3
Image for Text 3
<...>
```

Which is un-intuitive.

**Q1:** How can I change the result to:

```
Image for Text 1
Text 1
Image for Text 2
Text 2
Image for Text 3
Text 3
```

**Q2:** is it possible to write CSS in a way that creates the alternation by itself (without generating the CSS of course), while semantically keeping the HTML "in order"  (image/text/image/text/...)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to create child box and use flex-direction: column-reverse.
Check out the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Japusoy/d8q0utyc/2/) here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/purecss@2.0.6/build/pure-min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/purecss@2.0.6/build/grids-responsive-min.css" />
    <style>
        article {
            min-height: 100px;
            min-width: 200px;
        }
        .box {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
        }
        @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
             .box:first-child {
                flex-direction: column-reverse;
             }
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="pure-g">
        <div class="box">
            <article class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-2">Text 1</article>
            <article class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-2">Image for Text 1</article>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <article class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-2">Image for Text 2</article>
            <article class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-2">Text 2</article>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Great idea to wrap the articles in a box. I updated your idea for the complete solution: https://jsfiddle.net/ua5qwbvc/. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`order`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) along with an appropriate media query to achieve that:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 425px) {
  .pure-g > article:nth-child(2) {
    order: -1;
  }
}
```

Check out the updated jsFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/qw123o7g/1/) or the snippet below.

```css
.pure-g > article:nth-child(2) {
  order: -1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/purecss@2.0.6/build/pure-min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/purecss@2.0.6/build/grids-responsive-min.css" />
    <style>article { min-height: 100px; min-width: 200px; }</style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="pure-g">
      <article class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-2">Text 1</article>
      <article class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-2">Image for Text 1</article>
      <article class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-2">Image for Text 2</article>
      <article class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-2">Text 2</article>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. You answered correctly, so +1. But I just realized I didn't phrase the question correctly; updated the question. I would appreciate another look. :)